# Update password with confirmed rule is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a updatePassword method to update the password of a user.

There are some rules:

```
- the introduced actual password should be equal to the actual password of the user (users table has a column "password" on db)
- the new_password and new_password_confirm should be equal
- the actual_password and new_password should be different
```

I have the code below. But it appears always the validation error "The actual password confirmation does not match." even when the actual password introduced is correct.

Do you know where is the error?

```
 public function updatePassword(Request $request){
            $this->validate($request, [
            'actual_password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'new_password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            'new_password_confirm' => 'required|string|min:6|same:new_password',
            ]);

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->password = bcrypt($request->new_password);
            $user->save();

            Session::flash('success', 'updated.');

            return redirect()->back();
        }
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('user.updatePassword')}}" class="clearfix">
     {{csrf_field()}}
       <div>
            <label>New Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="actual_password" id="actual_password" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="new_password">New Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password" id="new_password" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Confirm password</label>
            <input type="password" name="new_password_confirm" class="form-control" id="new_password_confirm" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Update password"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Var dump of the submited pass:

```
array:3 [▼
  "actual_password" => "password"
  "new_password" => "passwordw"
  "new_password_confirm" => "passwordw"
]
```

Comment: Have you tried to dump the values and see them ? maybe you have a space...

Comment: The question is updated with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules can be simplified:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'actual_password' => 'required|string|min:6',
    'new_password' => 'required|string|min:6|different:actual_password',
    'new_password_confirm' => 'same:new_password',
]);
```

Some notes:

- **actual_password:** these rules are not really necessary, because you have to check the old password vs. the user input anyway. Actually, it could even be an issue in future, in case you change your password rules (e.g. `min:10` instead of `min:6`), because then you could potentially run into troubles changing your password (which would have been valid but isn't after the code change, so you couldn't even change it anymore).
- **new_password:** added the check `different:actual_password` to make sure the new password is different from the old one. It would also make sense to make use of a regex for this validation rule, e.g. to force different types of characters (lower- and uppercase letters, digits and special chars).
- **new_password_confirm:** using the suggested `same:new_password` rule of yours here is absolutely valid and a good solution. Personally, I even find the magic validation rule `confirm` mentioned by Dimitri Mostry a bit dangerous, because people will most likely not be able to understand the context in future (i.e. maintainability is not good). In the background, the `confirm` method does exactly the same as `same:other_field` ([see here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L359)). All of the other validation rules are obsolete, though. When you perform the already for `new_password`, you implicitely force them for the confirmation field as well when it has to be the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You may have confirmed in the wrong place:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'actual_password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        'new_password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'new_password_confirmation' => 'required|string|min:6|same:new_password',
        ]);
```

**Edit:** the second field has to end with `_confirmation`, not `_confirm`. This is a build-in requirement.

See [laravel validation confirmed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-confirmed).

Comment: The confirmed dont works to verify if the actual password of the user is correct? To check if the actual password introduced by the user is equal to the actual password sotred in the db?

Comment: You'll have to check this in the Controller. Especially with password fields for they are encrypted. You can't check this on browser level.